# Accessing Eager Loaded Transforms

Tags: assets, elementcriteriamodel, eager-loading

The craft docs on eager loading show you how to [eager load image transforms](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements#eager-loading-image-transform-indexes) in twig.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    with: [
        ['coolImage', { withTransforms: ['transform'] }]
    ]
}) %}
```

However it doesn't show you how to actually USE them once they're eager loaded. [Accessing the eager loaded element](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/eager-loading-elements#accessing-eager-loaded-elements) itself is easy:

```
{% set teaserImage = entry.coolImage[0] ?? null %}
```

But I'm not sure how to access the transform from there. Using getUrl('transform') appears to still result in an extra query per element loaded (compared with .url() and no transform).

```
{{ teaserImage.getUrl("transform") }} {# Boo - extra queries #}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the correct way to do it is using the url() method. I couldn't replicate the extra queries I mentioned in the question, and can confirm with some more testing that it doesn't cause any extra queries.

```
{{ teaserImage.url("transform") }}
```

or

```
{{ teaserImage.getUrl("transform") }}
```

Source: https://straightupcraft.com/articles/examples-of-eager-loading-elements-in-twig-and-php